2000's movie or TV episode about a young couple being kidnapped by criminals
I don't know anything about this movie except a couple details about the plot.

A group of criminals released from prison, maybe they're escaping. (two or three guys) - I'm not sure about the prison. Perhaps they just outlaws
They're going to desert town for some unfinished business.
The sheriff wants to catch them.
They can't enter the town. Because the sheriff took security measures. 
But they need to take money from the bank. They are taking a young couple (lovers) hostage.
They arrived to some town by car, then shot a boyfriend in his leg, because he was talking too much.
They're waiting on the hills in the town's entrance. 
Woman's boyfriend is staying with them. The young woman is going to the bank.
Criminals are watching with binoculars young woman.



I've watched in 2013-2014
It could be American/English. 
It is not a western movie.
It was probably not low budget. It is  crime-black comedy-thriller.

I've been trying to find the title of this movie for two years.

What time/era was it set in?

@Paulie_D  Could it be 90's or 2000's.

Sounds like Breakdown with Kurt Russell. Some details dont match tho. Remember anything else

It's not  "Breakdown"...
Criminals are the main characters, i think.

Do you know any actors in the movie? That would help

@coder0007 I don't remember, but may be famous and charismatic actors.  My memory is hazy.

@John I'm looking for a movie probably from the 2000's.

Are you sure it is not "Breakdown"? 
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118771/
There is a very similar scene in that movie. Small desert town, there is a sheriff (played by Rex Linn), criminals sending Kurt Russell's character to the local bank and watching him via binoculars from the hills. The criminals hold the wife hostage, that is how they blackmail Russell into withdrawing money from the bank. 
You can watch the complete movie below in good quality. Ca. at the 0:41:50 mark starts the scene where the criminals (their leader is J. T . Walsh) show Russell the desert town and send him to get the money:



I think this is the movie you are looking for, you are probably just mixing up the details a little bit.

I'm sure. I can not be wrong, because I've never seen "Breakdown"
I am looking  for a crime-black comedy.
She walks into the bank. The bad guys are watching her with binoculars lying on the hill.
Her boyfriend is staying with the bad guys.
Maybe, the young couple has found this money. But this money belongs to the bad guys.
For this reason the bad guys took them hostage.
Sorry. I can't do a good explanation. Bad English.

I genuinely thought that could be your movie. OK, then I don't know. :)
